# Android - permissions for services on remote process

Tags: android, service, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

Im making an app, and Im trying to have one of the services run on a remote process.

Manifest:

```
...
process=":myprocess"
...
```

When I try to run my service, I get the following error:

```
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: App has no android.permission.INTERNET permission.  Cannot check for distance model updates
```

If I remove the process line from the Manifest, everything is working. What gives??

I have tried to Google up information about Services and if they require their own permissions, but I have not found anything..

Full error log:

```
01-21 14:39:58.827 12442-12442/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: App has no android.permission.INTERNET permission.  Cannot check for distance model updates
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.StartRMData
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.StartRMData
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2275)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2239)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.Message.readFromParcel(Message.java:567)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.Message.access$000(Message.java:32)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:523)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:520)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.IMessenger$Stub.onTransact(IMessenger.java:51)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.StartRMData
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308) 
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2275) 
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2239) 
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.Message.readFromParcel(Message.java:567) 
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.Message.access$000(Message.java:32) 
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:523) 
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:520) 
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.IMessenger$Stub.onTransact(IMessenger.java:51) 
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446) 
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker E/Parcel:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker W/Binder: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.StartRMData
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker W/Binder:     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2289)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker W/Binder:     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2239)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker W/Binder:     at android.os.Message.readFromParcel(Message.java:567)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker W/Binder:     at android.os.Message.access$000(Message.java:32)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker W/Binder:     at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:523)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker W/Binder:     at android.os.Message$1.createFromParcel(Message.java:520)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker W/Binder:     at android.os.IMessenger$Stub.onTransact(IMessenger.java:51)
01-21 14:39:58.936 12442-12462/no.mytos.mytosbeacontracker W/Binder:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You see the error because the Android Beacon Library tries to fetch an update to its device distance calculation database.  If permission is not present to access the internet, this update fails, but the library continues to function normally using the built-in database.

Perhaps you get the error only with the process line present because in that case it does not inherit the permission from your app.

Bottom line: you should be able to just ignore this.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Maybe my app crashes from something else in there.. So bottom line 2: services in remote processes uses the same permissions as the app, and you should not have to (or can not even) give these their own permissions?

Comment: Well, does your app even request internet permission?

Comment: Yes, I have added the permission in the Manifest.

Comment: I am not 100% sure whether remote processes inherit permissions from the app that created them.  If you do not get this error with the permission added to your manifest, then that suggests they are inherited.  If you still get it, it suggests they are not.  And if they are not, there must be another way to set them.  Can you clarify which you are seeing?